# Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given,

Tags: php, doctrine

I have following Entity Class

```
<?php
namespace EvolisClientRequest\Model\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Email
{
    /**
     * @var \Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $sender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $body;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Request", mappedBy="Email")
     * @var Request
     */

    private $request;

    public function __construct(string $sender, string $subject, string $body,Request $request)
    {
        $this->sender = $expeditor;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->body = $body;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

}
```

On doing following it gives error:

```
$email = $this->email_dao->create ('srjfjgn@rkgjb.com','fkj','sdfkdjhbf',  new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($request_dao));
```

The line on which give error is:

```
$email = $this->email_dao->create ('srjfjgn@rkgjb.com','fkj','sdfkdjhbf',  new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection($request_dao));
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$request_dao` seems to be an object.

`ArrayCollection` accepts only `array` as constructor argument.